# Python: check if item exists in variable amount of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion

I'm working on a small search engine and I'm lost a certain point. I have multiple lists containing items, and I want to check which items exist in all lists. The amount of lists can vary, since they are created based on the number of words in the search query, done with:

```
index_list = [[] for i in range((len(query)+1))]
```

I figured I start with finding out what the shortest list is, since that is the maximum amount of items that need to be checked. So for example, with a three-word-search-query:

```
index_list[1]=[set(1,2,3,4,5)]
index_list[2]=[set(3,4,5,6,7)]
index_list[3]=[set(4,5,6,7)]

shortest_list = index_list[3]
```

(What the shortest list is, is figured out with a function, not relevant for now).

Now I want to check if the items of the shortest list, index_list[3], also exist in the other lists. In this case there are 3 lists in total, but when entering a longer search query, the amount of lists increase. I thought to do something with loops, like:

```
result = []
for element in shortest_list:
    for subelement in element:
        for element2 in index_list[1]:
            if subelement in element2:
                for element3 in index_list[2]:
                    if subelement in element3:
                        result.append(subelement)
```

So, the result should be:

```
[4, 5]
```

since these items exist in all lists.

But, the loop above won't work when there are more lists. As described earlier, I don't know the amount of lists beforehand because it depends on the amount of words in the search query. So basically the depth of my loop depends on the amount of lists I have.

When doing research I found some postings suggesting recursion may do the job. Unfortunately I'm not Python skilled that well.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which is good for unpicking nested loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use all [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and use `set.intersection` to find the common elements, also `{1,2,3,4,5}` is how to create a set of ints not `set(1,2,3,4,5)`:

```
index_list = [set() for i in range(4)]
index_list[0].update({1,2,3,4,5})
index_list[1].update({3,4,5,6,7})
index_list[2].update({4,5,6,7})

shortest_list = index_list[2]

print(shortest_list.intersection(*index_list[:2]))
set([4, 5])
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize intersection took an arbitrary number of arguments, that makes my code rather redundant.

Comment: yes, the `*index_list[:2]`  gets every set in the list excluding the last which is set to `shortest_list`.

Comment: That helps, thanks! Another question though: the number after *index_list (in this case :2) is put in manually? In your code, this stays :2, even if the amount of lists increase? Because it needs to adapt to the amount of lists, right?

Comment: if the smallest is always the last, `*index_list[:-1]` will always exclude the last

Comment: Hmm okay. Well, unfortunately the smallest list isn't always the last..so basically if there are X amount of lists (I have captured this amount in a variable already) then the statement should be something like: `print(shortest_list.intersection(*index_list[:X]))`. No luck yet unfortunately. You get what I mean?

Comment: sort by the length, `sorted(index_list,key=len)`

Comment: If you had a lot of data you could use a queue making sure the smallest element is always moved to the back of the queue

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for all the help! For anyone who's interested: I created a list of all the lists, and performed an intersection statement: `a=[[1,2,3],[2,3,5],[5,4,2]] print list(set.intersection(*map(set, a)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try to go about it the opposite way: First make a list of all the index lists by doing something like

```
index_list_list = []
for ix_list in get_index_lists(): #Or whatever
    index_list_list.append(ix_list)
```

Then you can loop through all of these, removing the elements in your 'remaining_items' list if they are not contained in the others:

```
remaining_items = shortest_list
for index_list in index_list_list:
    curr_remaining_items = copy(remaining_items)
    for element in curr_remaining_items:
        if element not in index_list:
            remaining_items.remove(element)
```

Your final 'remaining_items' list would then contain the elements that are common to all the lists.

Answer (score 0):

I written code by your approach. You can try out following code:

```
index_list=['1','2','3','4','5']
index_list1=['3','4','5','6','7']
index_list2=['4','5','6','7']

result = []
for element in index_list:
   for subelement in element:
       for element2 in index_list1:
           if subelement in element2:
               for element3 in index_list2:
                   if subelement in element3:
                       result.append(subelement)
print result
```

output:

```
['4', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little confusing that you appear to have something shadowing the built in type [set](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which happens to be built for precisely this type of job.

```
subset = set(shortest_list)
# Use map here to only lookup method once.
# We don't need the result, which will be a list of None.
map(subset.intersection_update, index_lists)

# Alternative: describe the reduction more directly
# Cost: rebuilds a new set for each list
subset = reduce(set.intersection, index_lists, set(shortest_list))
```

Note: As Padraic indicated in his answer, set.intersection and set.intersection_update both take an arbitrary number of arguments so it is unnecessary to use map or reduce in this case.

It is also by far preferable that all the lists already be sets, since the intersection can be optimized to the size of the smaller set, but a list intersection requires scanning the list.